# I cannot connect to a custom port on my Azure VM. My remote browser times out

Tags: azure

I am trying to solve a puzzling problem and hope that soeone can assist.  I have an extremely simple web application (Basically it's a Python Flask hello world' app)
I have it running on port 8081.  (Listening on IP 0.0.0.0).
I put in a network rule via the azure cloud shell for the VM that looks like this:

| Priority | Name | Port | Protocol | Source | Destination | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 360 | test | 8081 | Any | Any | Any | Allow |

I have verified that the app is listening on 0.0.0.0  port 8081
I am also able to access the app via the VM console with curl

If I point the app at port 80, then it works properly, but I just can't get access to it via port 8081.

The VM  is running Ubuntu Linux 20.04.   The internal firewall is disabled (sudo ufw status shows 'disabled').

Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to a connection test with the network watcher connection monitor
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/connection-monitor-overview